# Why does the following custom iterator implementation not play nice with `std::all_of`?

Tags: c++, iterator

I am working on some iterator type that needs to wrap another iterator. For some reason, the custom iterator is not well defined. For example, it does not compile when used with `std::all_of`, complaining about a mismatching  function call to `std::iterator_category`:

```
/opt/.../stl_algo.h:108:32: error: no matching function for call to '__iterator_category(Iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >&)'
108 |        std::__iterator_category(__first));
```

The custom iterator exposes a public `iterator_category` type, so I am not sure what the problem is here. To demonstrate the issue, the custom iterator simply wraps some other iterator type:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template<typename It>
struct Iterator
{
  using difference_type = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type;
  using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type;
  using pointer = value_type*;
  using reference_type = value_type&;
  using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

  Iterator(It it) : it_{it} {}

  friend bool operator==(const Iterator& x, const Iterator& y) { return x.it_ == y.it_; }
  friend bool operator!=(const Iterator& x, const Iterator& y) { return !(x == y); }

  Iterator& operator++()
  {
    ++it_;
    return *this;
  }
  Iterator operator++(int)
  {
    Iterator it{*this};
    this->operator++();
    return it;
  }

  reference_type operator*() { return *it_; }

private:
  It it_;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};

  auto first{Iterator{v.begin()}};
  auto last{Iterator{v.end()}};
  std::all_of(first, last, [](auto) { return true; });
}
```

The compiler errors are solved in case the iterator derives from `std::iterator`:

```
struct Iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, typename It::value_type>
```

(see: https://godbolt.org/z/vMfj38)

So `std::iterator` brings something to the table that is missing from the definition of `Iterator` above, but what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) requires a `reference` member type, not `reference_type`. Fixing that allows it to compile successfully:

```cpp
using reference/*_type*/ = value_type&;
...
reference/*_type*/ operator*() { return *it_; }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PzK9fq

Comment: Nice :) That error message is completely unhelpful :(

Comment: @cigien for me, the hint was `candidate std::__iterator_category(const _Iter&) template argument deduction/substitution failed`, so I figured the traits weren't being satisfied in some way. By comparing against documentation, it was just a matter of finding which member type wasn't satisfied.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that a trait was wrong. It's just annoying that the error message (in all compilers) points directly to the wrong trait :p

Comment: Ouch, thank you! Good to know how you got to the answer  as well.